# Python: Nested list with repeated name of strings and different integers. How can I

Tags: python, string, integer, nested-lists

If I have the following nested list:

products.store = [['Shampoo', 35], ['Soap', 100], ['Soap', 150],['Towels', 45], ['Shampoo', 55]]

How can I write a program where each product is associated to total amount of products?

So that the output will still be in a nested list, like this:
[['Shampoo', 90], ['Soap', 250],['Towels', 45]]

I have tried multiple solutions, but have failed to make the integers associated to a singular product.

Sorry if this is an easy question, it is my first term in university with coding.
(Not for homework, a test or something like that). I would just love to learn how to improve my codes and better understand:) Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried already? Stack overflow is meant to help

Comment: Oh sorry! Deleted the failed codes since I was so far off and had no idea. So I dont have the exact codes now. First time asking question here, so I apologise.
Tried making it into a string, then using for val in(.... split, out.append, etc.), but with no luck on the hours of failed tries haha:) So winded up asking in case some one else knew, so I could learn from you who are more informed and skilled:)

Comment: Start with `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
products = [
    ["Shampoo", 35],
    ["Soap", 100],
    ["Soap", 150],
    ["Towels", 45],
    ["Shampoo", 55],
]

out = {}
for a, b in products:
    out[a] = out.get(a, 0) + b

out = list(map(list, out.items()))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[["Shampoo", 90], ["Soap", 250], ["Towels", 45]]
```